# Need help on understanding Boost FAQ on header-only libraries

Tags: c++, boost, centos7

I was reading [installing Boost from sources](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/install.html#boost_regex.install.building_from_source) when I just cross-referenced [enter link description here](http://www.boost.org/build/doc/html/bbv2/faq/header-only-libraries.html) which says:

> However, with Boost.Build a header-only library can be declared as
>   Boost.Build target and all dependents can use such library without
>   having to remember whether it is a header-only library or not.

Then there is a description as:

```
alias my-lib
    : # no sources
    : # no build requirements
    : # no default build
    : <include>whatever ;
```

How is this connected and what it is trying to explain with the above alias rule?

Comment: you cross referenced what? a link description?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FAQ entry has nothing to do with installing the Boost library on your system.

The FAQ entry is for people who use Boost.Build as their build system (as opposed to make, CMake, etc). They observe that some libraries are header-only, where the entire library only exists in header files and does not require linking a `.a` or `.so`. In some build systems it's difficult to specify such libraries as dependencies, as the build system doesn't actually build them, doesn't link them, and might not even know they exist (if installed in the include path). Boost.Build uses that `alias` command to specify such libraries.

One example of a header-only library is Boost itself, where most of its modules only live in header files.